# Constructing complete lattices from total functions to posets

Tags: lattice-orders, programming

So I ran into this statement that says that the lowest upper bound of a set Y in L, a function space built like L = {f : S → L1 | f is a total function} is somehow related to the joins of the f(s)'s within the original L1 poset, but I don't get the **λs.** business. What does this say?

> Let $L_1 = (L_1, \sqsubseteq) $ be a poset and $S$ be a set.

> Define $ L = (L, \sqsubseteq)$ by $ L = \{f: S \rightarrow L_1 | f $ is a total function$ \} $ and $ f \sqsubseteq f' $ iff $\forall s \in S: f(s) \sqsubseteq_1 f'(s)$.

> Then, L is a poset. Also, if $L_1$ is a complete lattice, then $L$ is also one. Furthermore:

> $$ \bigsqcup Y = \lambda s. \bigsqcup \{f(s) | f \in Y \} $$

> and $ \perp = \lambda s.\perp $ and similarly for $ \sqcap Y$ and $\top $

[image from original text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BspNn.png)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) + [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.

Comment: It seems to be just a matter of notation. You see, $Y$ is a set of functions, so $\bigvee Y$ must also be one (given that $L$ is a complete lattice). So there is an image $(\bigvee Y)(s)$ for each $s \in S$, and likewise for the other cases. Meanwhile, you should type your question rather than provide a link. See also the links in the comment above.

Comment: The notation "$\lambda x.a$" just means "The function which, on input $x$, returns $a$." So e.g. in the natural numbers "$\lambda x.x+1$" is the usual successor function, and in the context of the post "$\lambda s.\perp$" is the constant function always returning $\perp$. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'll use a different notation and prove just the join part of the complete lattice.
I won't use the $L_1$ notation as it keeps confusing me...

We have a poset $\mathbf P = (P,\leq)$ and a set $S$ and define the poset $\mathbf L = (L,\leq)$ where $L = P^S$ (the set of maps from $S$ to $P$), with the order defined by
$$f \leq f' \iff f(s) \leq f'(s), \,\text{ for all } s \in S.$$

I'll leave it to you to show that $\mathbf L$ is a poset (it seems you have no problem with that).

If $\mathbf P$ is a complete lattice, then you seem to have the task of proving that $\mathbf L$ is a complete lattice where

1. For $Y \subseteq L$, the join of $Y$ is given by
   $$\left(\bigvee Y\right)(s) = \bigvee\{f(s):f \in Y\}.$$
2. For $Y \subseteq L$, the meet of $Y$ is given by
   $$\left(\bigwedge Y\right)(s) = \bigwedge\{f(s):f \in Y\}.$$
3. $\bot(s) = \bot$.
4. $\top(s) = \top$.

Let us prove 1.
Define $f_Y(s) = \bigvee\{f(s):f \in Y\}$.
We want to prove that $\bigvee Y = f_Y$.

If $g \in Y$ then $g(s) \leq \bigvee\{f(s):f \in Y\} = f_Y(s)$, whence $g \leq f_Y$, and so $f_Y$ is an upper bound of $Y$.

Let $h$ be an upper bound of $Y$.
If we prove that $f_Y \leq h$, then we conclude that $f_Y$ is the least upper bound of $Y$, that is, $f_Y = \bigvee Y$.
As $h$ is an upper bound of $Y$, we have $g \leq h$, for any $g \in Y$, or yet, $g(s) \leq h(s)$ for any $g \in Y$ and any $s \in S$.
Thus,
$$f_Y(s) = \bigvee\{f(s) : f \in Y\} \leq h(s),$$
and thus $f_Y \leq h$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Yeah, once I got the lambda notation this is straightforward, still, thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @AttilaSzász Thanks. It was not clear for me if you just didn't understand what was the $\lambda$ all about, or if you actually didn't realize that $\bigvee Y$ should be a function, and why it took that form. Best regards.